# SQL Server 2012 - How to dynamically select data from a view based on user privilleges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am creating a security layer on few databases. As part of that I have to create a view in `Original_Database` that joins two tables (union) from different databases, `Chained_Database1` and `Chained_Database2`.

```sql
USE Original_Database;
GO 

CREATE VIEW QueryATable
AS
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database1.dbo.ATable
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database2.dbo.ATable;
GO
```

If user usergroupA (Usergroup) logs in and selects from the view `QueryATable` from `Original_Database` then he should be able to see only data from `Chained_Database1.dbo.ATable`.

Likewise if usergroupB logs in and selects from the view `QueryATable`, then he should be able to see only data from `Chained_Database2.dbo.ATable`.

I have tried giving different permissions to the users. It's either denying view access or giving result from two tables.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create separate view for providing access to users only for accessing one table. I am not understanding the requirement clearly

Comment: Did you mean that usergroupB should only see data from Database2?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, the `UNION` is pointless and would only slow performance since you would select from both data sets... and then explicitly limit it to one. Theoretically you'd have a look up table for the user who ran the query, and you'd limit the results in the `WHERE` clause since you can't user parameters in a view. So, don't do the union. Instead create two separate views.

```
CREATE VIEW QueryATable
AS
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database1.dbo.ATable
    GRANT SELECT ON QueryATable TO <who ever...>
GO


CREATE VIEW QueryBTable
AS
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database2.dbo.ATable
    GRANT SELECT ON QueryBTable TO <who ever...>
GO
```

If you don't want to create separate views then you could handle this in a `STORED PROCEDURE` or some other way perhaps...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedure(@userID)
AS

IF 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LookUpTableA WHERE userID = @userID)
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database1.dbo.ATable
IF 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LookUpTableB WHERE userID = @userID)
    SELECT * FROM Chained_Database2.dbo.ATable
ELSE
    SELECT 'User Not Valid'
GO
```

Note that this assumes the user would only be in one of the look up tables. If they were in both you'd need to handle it differently.

Comment: Simon, Thx for ur answer. my exact requirement is All usergroups should only access single schema and View from Original database. This singe view from Original database should join views from Chained_Database1&2. I was thinking whether there is any permission that can be assigned to usergroupA that only check the existence of the view in the chained_database2 but not a select access when UsergroupA selects view Original_Database .QueryATable. So that the view doesn't throw any error but it will just fetch data from chained_database1. Hope info makes sense.

Comment: I explained how to do that using procedures or a look up table with a view. It's a terrible idea though

Comment: Your are right any additional constraints or joins in main view will definitely be a bad idea in performance point of view. But I'm purely trying to see in role permissions point of view whether I can achieve this assigning a role to usergroupA that has got permissions to just validate the view in chained_database2 but not do any thing else. We have inbuilt object permissions Alter, Control, delete, execute, take ownership, impersonate, insert, update, receive, create, view definition, view change tracking, Select, references. Not sure whether any of these can work with what I am looking for.

Comment: The only way to restrict the results of this view would be by joining to a reference table of data base permissions for each user